# adding dependencies to a conda environment yaml file

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a process to setup an initial project whereby I create a standardised conda environment based on a yaml file.

`conda env create -f environment.yaml`

The yaml file looks something like this

```
name: testA
channels:
- conda-forge
- defaults
- anaconda
dependencies:
- python=3.6.3=1
- yaml=0.1.7=0 
- connexion=1.1.10=py36_0
- setuptools=38.4.0=py36_0
- pymongo=3.4.0=py36_0
- gunicorn=19.8.1=py36_0
- flask-cors=3.0.6=py36_0
```

As the project progresses a user might add another library

`conda install scikit-learn`

**Is it possible to append the updated conda environment to original environment.yaml ???** - I know I can overwrite with

`conda env export > environment.yaml`

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? You've identified the command to update the yaml file...

Comment: I want to append not overwrite. Specifically the dependencies

Comment: But what changes when you overwrite? Isn't the effect just to append the new packages? For what it's worth, there's no method to append that I know of, you have to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the input. My use case is I am creating a framework for development with a conda environment. Thereafter the user can add to the environment and I wanted to update as eventually that environment is wrapped in a micro-service through docker. I'll write some custom method to achieve.